# Regular expression matching only the first match

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to use regular expressions to find repeating patterns in a string. I tested my RegExp in a tester and I think it's no problem with my Regex, but my code return only the first match(0.0000000000000000) and not the other matches:

Here is my code:

```
Dim searchstr As String
Dim regexp As Object
Dim colregmatch As MatchCollection

searchstr = "ST/X   0.0000000000000000   6.4000000000000004   12.8000000000000010   19.1999999999999990   25.6000000000000010   32.0000000000000000"
Set regexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With regexp
        .Pattern = "([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\s*"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = False
End With
Set colregmatch = regexp.Execute(searchstr)
If colregmatch.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each Match In colregmatch
           MsgBox Match
        Next Match
End If
```

Would you please help me to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set Global flag to first true, then to false.

```
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = False
```

Try to remove the last one.